# what's the relation between view and view.layer?

Tags: ios, core-animation

What's the relation between view and view.layer. For example, view.layer has property position. and view has property center. If I change the position of layer, does view change center property? If I change the bounds of view.layer, does view change its bounds property as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views are backed by layers. As stackmonster says, a layer describes the low-level drawing context the system uses to render a rectangular area of content to the screen.

The other things stackmonster said about not manipulating layers directly, and poor animation performance, are flat-out wrong. Core Animation is based on layers. For many simple animations you can use UIView animation, but there are whole classes of animation and other things that require you to create and use layers directly. All CAAnimation objects act on layers, and there are lots of very cool tricks you can only do by manipulating layers directly. I use layers all the time for drawing and animation.

Layers and views use slightly different properties to control their position on the screen. As you say, a view has a center property and a layer has a position property. They are analogous.

Answer (score 0):

A layer represents a graphical context which share potentially multiple clipping regions but will also potentially aggregate drawing operations for performance reasons, and sometimes this is constrained by overlapping views or animation effects that have conflicting alpha (transparency) values.

In general you dont manually manipulate layers, however you may reference them in API calls so that the underlying framework can try and sort all of this out for you.  Otherwise you would have pretty horrible animation performance in iOS.

Unless you are doing very low level graphics coding I dont know why you would manipulate a layers bounds directly.

Comment: And keep in mind since objective C doesnt support private methods in any real way, the API will show public methods that are really only intended for subclassing.